# Certain git commands have a problem running on git mobile

Tags: git, powershell

Trying to get this portable git to do pulls. I can get it working if I install git, but we are wanting to get this distributed without having to install all of git on everyone's workstation. Powershell 7

Here is one output working but another not

```
PS D:\FusionLoginScript> & "D:\FusionLoginScript\bin\PortableGit\mingw64\bin\git" pull
git: 'remote-http' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.

PS D:\FusionLoginScript> & "D:\FusionLoginScript\bin\PortableGit\mingw64\bin\git" status
On branch development
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/development' by 1 commit.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
        modified:   sharedfunctions.ps1

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
        bin/
```

Comment: Can Git locate `git-remote-http.exe`?  If not, try updating your %PATH% ahead of `git pull`